# Multi language in FuelCMS

Tags: php, codeigniter, multilingual, fuelcms

I'm trying to make a multilanguage site in codeigniter with fuelCMS. I have figured out some things:

**I have added the multilanguage option in MY_fuel.php**

```
$config['language_mode'] = 'segment';
$config['settings']['languages'] =  array(
                        'type' => 'keyval',
                        'fields' => array(
                                'key' => array('ignore_representative' => TRUE),
                                'label' => array('ignore_representative' => TRUE),
                            ),
                        'class' => 'repeatable',
                        'repeatable' => TRUE,
                        'ignore_representative' => TRUE
                    );
```

**I have set up a navigation for the different languages.**

```
<?php echo fuel_nav(array('container_tag_id' => 'masterMenu', 'item_id_prefix' => 'menu-item','subcontainer_tag_class' => array("subMenu"),'language' => $this->fuel->language->selected())); ?>
```

**The navigation is like:**

> default en:
>
> - about
> - products/producta
> - products/productb

**And the other language:**

> nl:
>
> - overons
> - producten/producta
> - producten/productb

It shows the correct navigation. But the selected language isn't "imported" in the url. So it dissapears always.

Example:
If I'm on the about page (english default) and I change the language to nl. It still shows the about page, but with the correct dutch navigation. So I have some questions about it.

- *(SOLVED THIS PART) Is there a possibility to have the language always in the url? I looked in the menu class (http://docs.getfuelcms.com/libraries/menu) but couldn't add it.*
- Can I have 1 page in CMS that has multilanguage in it? If I change the language, that It will show the correct dutch text?

Something like

```
{language=en}About the company{/language}
{language=nl}Over het bedrijf{/language}
```

- Or is there another solution? If I change the language, maybe always go to the homepage of that language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve one part of my problem.

I added a page "overons" (language parameter to NL, location overons)
And then I manually added the navigation for this page with location parameter nl/overons. This works.

Only if I change the language while I'm on a english page, it stays in English. So I can't link the pages to the translated pages.

It seems to be possible if I add them manually in the viewfolder. But I don't know how to fix that in the CMS.

> View Pages
>
> Additionally, if your pages are using views and there is a language
>   value set by the user using Fuel_language, it will first look for a
>   view file in the views/language/{language}/ folder and if it doesn't
>   find it, it will default to just the views folder.

EDIT:

I have used another method to solve it. Only not yet imported into the CMS.

I have created the **following structure** in views:

> language/
>
> language/fr/
>
> language/fr/home.php
>
> language/fr/company.php

-

> language/nl/
>
> language/nl/home.php
>
> language/nl/company.php

And in the **global views map**, I **added home & company.php**.

And for the correct menu I have this code in
**views/_variables/nav.php**

```
if($this->fuel->language->selected() == "nl"){

$nav['home'] = 'Home';
$nav['contact'] = 'Contact';
$nav['company'] = 'Over ons';

}
if($this->fuel->language->selected() == "en"){

    $nav['home'] = 'Home';
    $nav['contact'] = 'Contact';
    $nav['company'] = 'About us';

}

if($this->fuel->language->selected() == "fr"){

    $nav['home'] = 'Accueil';
    $nav['contact'] = 'Contact';
    $nav['company'] = 'Société';

}
```